# Convert number of 4, 5 or 6 digits to a date

Tags: excel, vba, date

I found this code online. I find it very convenient especially when encoding various dates.

The result is not consistent.

Sometimes it correctly produce the answer but it just output blank with a glimpse of a would be output but an incorrect date.

This VBA will convert ex 1521 to 05-Jan-21 inputting this in sequence in the next row will sometime produce 05-Jan-21, and sometimes 29-feb-04 then it will turn blank after okay of msg box.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Selection.Count > 1 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

If Not Intersect(Range("a2:b100"), Target) Is Nothing Then

    DLen = Len(Target)
    
    If DLen = 4 Then
        DateV = DateValue(Left(Target, 1) & "-" & Mid(Target, 2, 1) & "-" & Right(Target, 2))
    ElseIf DLen = 5 Then
        DateV = DateValue(Left(Target, 1) & "-" & Mid(Target, 2, 2) & "-" & Right(Target, 2))
    ElseIf DLen = 6 Then
        DateV = DateValue(Left(Target, 2) & "-" & Mid(Target, 3, 2) & "-" & Right(Target, 2))
        
    ElseIf DLen > 6 Then
        MsgBox "less than 6"
    
    End If
    
    Target.NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yy"
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target = DateV
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

End Sub
```

Output during test

[image]

Answer (score -1):

What's going on here is that when you enter 1521, sometimes Excel automatically converts that to a date.  Integer 1521 converts to 2/29/1904.  So if Excel thinks you want the cell formatted as a date, it converts it.  Then len(2/29/1904) is 9, so you get the error message (which should be MORE than 6, BTW).

So, as usual, the code is doing what it was programmed to do. But there's a mix up in Excel before the VBA code even executes.  That's why it flashes the date.

You should try to fix the code, which is faulty for length 5.  It will convert that as if the string is DMMYY, but it could be DDMYY. 11255 could be 11-Feb-55 or 1-Dec-55.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving the reason for the cause of error. i think for the 5 length character  that is really very difficult to discern if the first 2 digits is part of a month or just a day. I guess the code is really faulty